# Remove numbered keys only, not value, from JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm building a JSON with PHP, and the keys can't be quoted,
because I need to import it into Neo4j.

I'm using this to build it in PHP, inside a loop:

```
$contacts[$contact_key]["addr"][$addr_key]["zipcode"] = $zip_match[0];
$contacts[$contact_key]["addr"][$addr_key]["housenumber"] = $house_match[0];
```

And eventualy I use:

```
$reencoded = json_encode($contacts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);        
$reencoded = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $reencoded);
```

So this is a part of the JSON string result:

```
{addr:{1:{zipcode:"1315 GN",housenumber:"1229P;"}}
```

But I can't have numbered keys like `1:`, `2:` ect.
because that gives me a error in Neo4j.

I preferly need to achieve this format:

```
{addr: [{zipcode:"1315 GN",housenumber:"1229P"}]
```

How can I make a list of adresses for a contact person,
without having numbered keys?

Comment: I think if you start `$contact_key` at 0 and increment it then the numbers will be absent in the JSON.  But the non-quoted keys is NOT valid JSON so what is Neo4j doing?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to remove the numeric keys you're getting from `$addr_key` from your JSON, just don't include them to begin with.

For the code inside your loop, you can add the addresses with `[]` instead, like this:

```
$address = ['zipcode' => $zip_match[0], 'housenumber' => $house_match[0]];
$contacts[$contact_key]["addr"][] = $address;
```

Comment: Thanks code looks cleaner now, but I still get the numbers. Isn't it because $contacts[$contact_key]["addr"] is already filled/not empty?

Comment: When you add the addresses using `[]`, PHP will automatically create zero-based integer indexes for the `addr` array. When you `json_encode` an array like that, you _should_ end up with a JSON array (`[]`) rather than a JSON object (`{}`). The keys should not be showing up in the JSON.

Comment: I now use: `$contacts[$contact_key]["addrs"][]` to have a zero-based integer index, and at the start of the loop I do: `unset($contacts[$contact_key]["addr"]);` I now have a empty `addr: [] ` present in the JSON result. But I think I can be happy right now.